# How to print no line on python3

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication

I want to print like this on python3

```
[1, 2, 3]   [3, 2, 1]   [4, 4, 4]
[4, 5, 6] + [6, 5, 4] = [10, 10, 10]
[7, 8, 9]   [9, 8, 7]   [16, 16, 16]
```

But its showing like this :

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
+
[3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4]
[9, 8, 7]
=
[4, 4, 4]
[10, 10, 10]
[16, 16, 16]
```

Here is my code : 
https://codeshare.io/29rgr7

Comment: Please, add your code

Comment: have a look at [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

Comment: It is difficult to help without knowing your input format. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29rgr7

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a vargs argument ot print method in python3, which is exactly what you are looking for

```
print([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [4, 4, 4])
print([4, 5, 6], '+', [6, 5, 4], '=', [10, 10, 10])
print([7, 8, 9], [9, 8, 7], [16, 16, 16])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print